# Mysql delete duplicate record but keep the row which contain most value

Tags: mysql

if I have following table :

```
+------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| id   | name   | Surnmae | email |address|
+------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| 1    |        | Lee     | aaa   |23 a st|
| 2    | a      |         | aaa   |       |
| 3    | c      |         | ccc   |       |
+------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
```

How can I delete duplicate record base on email but keep the record which contains most value and give the following result?

```
+------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| id   | name   | Surnmae | email |address|
+------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| 1    |        |  Lee    | aaa   |23 a st|
| 3    | c      |         | ccc   |       |
+------+--------+---------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Take a look at DISTINCT in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729428/eliminate-partial-duplicate-rows-from-result-set

Comment: yes, this is just an example for my case, because I have many column in one record in my table. For example, 5 of them have same email address, but 1 of the 5 has name, address and stuff, but the other 4 only have name, I want to keep the record which has most value like name, address, and delete the other duplication.

Comment: HMM, off the top of my head: SELECT from table name, address, stuff WHERE name NOT NULL AND address NOT NULL AND stuff NOT NULL should get you only records that are fully populated

Comment: This is a interesting idea, but I got 41 column:( I believe there should be a easier way to do this

Comment: I'm not on a box with a db to test this on , so make a copy before trying: SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE col IS NOT NULL;

Comment: in the 41 columns, all of them have at least 10 empty columns(T_T)

Comment: I don't think the sample data set is adequately representative of the problem

Comment: I just update the sample data, now it should be adequately representative of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got a way, but it is kind ok stupid, it works for small table just like the one I provided above:

```
DELETE FROM table1
 WHERE firstname NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.firstname)
                            FROM table1 n
                        GROUP BY n.email) x) 
OR lastname NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.lastname)
                            FROM table1 n
                        GROUP BY n.email) x)
OR address NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.address)
                            FROM table1 n
                        GROUP BY n.email) x)
```

but does anyone has an idea which can simplif my query?? like one line query?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this i assume ur table name is members

```
delete t1 from  members LEFT JOIN members t1 ON members.email = t1.email AND  members.id != t1.id  AND IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(members.Surnmae ),0) > IFNULL(CHAR_LENGTH(t1.Surnmae ),0) WHERE t1.id > 0;
```

Comment: Hi mate, I got this error: Unexpected token. (near "t1" at position 7)

Comment: can you share your query with your table ?

Comment: delete t1 from table1 LEFT JOIN table1 t1 
  ON table1.email = t1.email 
  AND  table1.id != t1.id 
  AND CHAR_LENGTH(table1.firstname) > CHAR_LENGTH(t1.firstname ) 
  AND CHAR_LENGTH(table1.lastname ) > CHAR_LENGTH(t1.lastname ) WHERE t1.id > 0;

Comment: Can you check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cfb82/16. if we change select t1.* to delete t1 then it will delete that row

Comment: Hi man, it might be work in SQL, but it still shows error "#1054 - Unknown column 't1.id' in 'where clause'", I think it might not work for mySQL?

Comment: In Sql fiddle i selected mysql 5.6 may its because of version changes in mysql.